# How create an alert in the delete function without confirm of the JavaScript, only AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, alert

I have a small project to create the TODO List in CRUD. But have a specification that I can't finish the function. It's an alert in the delete function but can't have a alert in JavaScript must be a AngularJS function.

```
 $scope.delete = function() {
      $scope.index = this.$index;
       $scope.showConfirm = true;
    }

    $scope.yes = function(){
      $scope.tasks.splice($scope.index, 1);
        $scope.showConfirm = false;
    }

    $scope.no = function(){
       $scope.showConfirm = false;
    }
```

Link: https://plnkr.co/edit/zReV2knGp6dxZcfPoqld?p=preview

Comment: can you explain the question more

Comment: Why dont you use bootstrap? It has modal or dropdown where you can use as a dialog to confirm delete.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't have a confirm. Why would that hurt anything? Seems like you're making your life harder for no reason. There needs to be more explanation.

Comment: @arjabbar exact thoughts

Comment: Why would you want to take a long route? Are you facing browser issues? AngularJS cannot be written without JS

Comment: I edited the question. Now, I think that stay better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

In a pure angularJS app I would use the [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) plugin:

```
swal({
   title: "Are you sure?",
   text: "You will not be able to recover this task!",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
   confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
   closeOnConfirm: false
}, function(){
   swal("Deleted!", "Your taske has been deleted.", "success");
});
```

--OLD ANSWER
Only angularJS allowed?

You can use plain javascript:

```
  if(confirm("Delete task?"))
    $scope.tasks.splice(this.$index, 1);
```

Comment: He said "without confirm of the JavaScript, only AngularJS?"

Answer (score 0):

I dont now why you dont want the `confirm` function but if you still need it, here's a simple trick designed for you code that will help you, without using any 3rd party library.

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/p6Wlsy1OQC98wLai6grs?p=preview)

You can just adjust the style for the confirmation box.

Comment: Hello Green Fox!

Here don't delete the tasks.

Comment: What do you mean? @DouglasGorniMello Its working for me. Are you sure?

Comment: @DouglasGorniMello Im sorry I missed something, link is updated now.